# *ix based Morphing software?

Tags: image-manipulation

Morphing is `"a special effect in motion pictures and animations that changes (or morphs) one image into another through a seamless transition"`, according to Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing). My friend recommended some Aftereffects software in Mac but I feel there must be something at least on development also in *ix world because the algorithms and technology seem to be developing so rapidly.

Which *ix tools do you use for Morphing images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can do that. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/shapemorph/) for you.